# Underscore after a variable name in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, naming-conventions

I am deciphering someone else's code and I see the following:

```
def get_set_string(set_):
     if PY3:
         return str(set_)
     else:
         return str(set_)
```

Does the underscore AFTER the variable mean anything or is this just a part of the variable's name and means nothing?

Comment: It's just part of the name. You'll need to ask the author.

Comment: It's to distinguish it from `set`, the built-in set type, to avoid shadowing the name - [*"`single_trailing_underscore_ `: used by convention to avoid conflicts with Python keyword"*](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#descriptive-naming-styles).

Comment: thank you for clarifying this

Answer (score 70, accepted):

No semantics are associated with a trailing underscore. According to [`PEP 8`](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#descriptive-naming-styles), the style guide for Python, users are urged to use trailing underscores in order to not conflict with Python keywords and/or Python built-ins:

> `single_trailing_underscore_` : used by convention to avoid conflicts with Python keyword, e.g.
>
> `Tkinter.Toplevel(master, class_='ClassName')`

Using `set_` means that the built-in name for sets, i.e `set`, won't get shadowed and lose its known reference during the function call.

Answer (score 12):

It means nothing. I believe the one who wrote this wanted a variable name designating a set, but `set` is a type in Python (which creates a set), so he added the underscore.