# File Not Found Error: [Errno 2] When File is in correct place

Tags: python

I'm running this code in Sublime Text 3 with python 3.6 installed. 
The Error I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\SublimeCode\Creating list from txt.pyw", line 3, in <module>
    List = open('C:\SublimeCode\Employee\EmployeeList.txt').readlines()
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 
'C:\\SublimeCode\\Employee\\EmployeeList.txt'
```

I have all these folders as listed in the correct places but yet I get the error.
Code:

```
List = open('C:\SublimeCode\Employee\EmployeeList.txt').readlines()

print(List)
```

Comment: Maybe this helps https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2953834/windows-path-in-python

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First using `\` is a [string literal](https://docs.python.org/2.0/ref/strings.html) you must use a `\\` to escape this property (or you can use `/` instead) and you should also set a property as well as read the file before attempting to manipulate the contents.

You can set the property using `r` (in this case)

```
list_ = open('C:\\SublimeCode\\Employee\\EmployeeList.txt', 'r').readlines()
print(list_)
```

You should not use capitals in variables only to set constants.  Since list is a function you can escape this property by adding a `_` after it see [pep8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) and as described in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39109398/underscore-after-a-variable-name-in-python).

Comment: This hasn't solved the problem. I ran the code provided and I'm still getting the same error. Any other reasons why this might be happening?

Comment: @Rubyink  Duh I missed out the most important point.  Could you please run it again I have edited my code?

Comment: That worked. It found the file but hasn't been able to read it?   File "C:\SublimeCode\Creating list from txt.pyw", line 4, in <module>
    list_.readlines()
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'readlines'

Comment: @Rubyink  Yes I've found the problem.  `readlines()` *does* read the file.  So using `read()` is totally unnecessary.  Both mistakes were from my end *sorry*.